# Technical Documentation Page (freeCodeCamp Responsive Web Design project)

Tags: html, css

I would appreciate som feedback on my Technical Document Page. I am doing the freeCodeCamp curriculum and a [Technical Document Page](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-projects/build-a-technical-documentation-page) is one of the Responsive Web Design Projects using only HTML/CSS.

I am especially interested in feedback regarding best practice, naming conventions and efficient code.

---

The code is also [on GitHub](https://oyvind-solberg.github.io/fcc-technical-document-page/).

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>Learn HTML Basics</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container">
            <header id="top-header">
                <div class="main-heading">
                    <h1>
                        <span class="heading-start">Learn </span>HTML<span
                            class="heading-end"
                        >
                            Basics</span
                        >
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="heading-text">
                    <p>
                        This module contains articles, which will take you
                        through all the basic theory of HTML.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="padding-container">
                <div class="sub-container">
                    <aside>
                        <nav id="navbar">
                            <header>
                                HTML Documentation
                            </header>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        class="nav-link nav-heading"
                                        href="#Getting_started_with_HTML"
                                        >Getting started with HTML</a
                                    >
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#What_is_HTML?"
                                                >What is HTML?</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Anatomy_of_an_HTML_element"
                                                >Anatomy of an HTML element</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        class="nav-link nav-heading"
                                        href="#What’s_in_the_head?"
                                        >What’s in the head?</a
                                    >
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#What_is_the_HTML_head?"
                                                >What is the HTML head?</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Adding_a_title"
                                                >Adding a title</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        class="nav-link nav-heading"
                                        href="#HTML_text_fundamentals"
                                        >HTML text fundamentals</a
                                    >
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Headings_and_Paragraphs"
                                                >Headings and Paragraphs</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Lists"
                                                >Lists</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        class="nav-link nav-heading"
                                        href="#Creating_hyperlinks"
                                        >Creating hyperlinks</a
                                    >
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#What_is_a_hyperlink?"
                                                >What is a hyperlink?</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Anatomy_of_a_link"
                                                >Anatomy of a link</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        class="nav-link nav-heading"
                                        href="#Advanced_text_formatting"
                                        >Advanced text formatting</a
                                    >
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Description_lists"
                                                >Description lists</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="nav-link-sub"
                                                href="#Quotations"
                                                >Quotations</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        class="nav-link nav-heading"
                                        href="#Reference"
                                        >Reference</a
                                    >
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </aside>

                    <main id="main-doc">
                        <section
                            class="main-section"
                            id="Getting_started_with_HTML"
                        >
                            <header>
                                <h2>Getting started with HTML</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p>
                                In this article we cover the absolute basics of
                                HTML, to get you started. We define elements,
                                attributes, and all the other important terms
                                you may have heard, and where they fit into the
                                language. We also show how an HTML element is
                                structured, how a typical HTML page is
                                structured, and explain other important basic
                                language features. Along the way, we'll play
                                with some HTML to get you interested!
                            </p>
                            <article>
                                <div id="What_is_HTML?">
                                    <h3>What is HTML?</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) is not
                                        a programming language; it is a markup
                                        language used to tell your browser how
                                        to structure the web pages you visit. It
                                        can be as complicated or as simple as
                                        the web developer wishes it to be. HTML
                                        consists of a series of elements, which
                                        you use to enclose, wrap, or mark up
                                        different parts of the content to make
                                        it appear or act a certain way. The
                                        enclosing tags can make a bit of content
                                        into a hyperlink to link to another page
                                        on the web, italicize words, and so on.
                                        For example, take the following line of
                                        content:
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>My cat is very grumpy</code>
                                </pre>
                                    <p>
                                        If we wanted the line to stand by
                                        itself, we could specify that it is a
                                        paragraph by enclosing it in a paragraph
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >(&lt;p&gt;)</code
                                        >
                                        element:
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>&lt;p&gt;My cat is very grumpy&lt;p&gt;</code>
                                </pre>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Anatomy_of_an_HTML_element">
                                    <h3>Anatomy of an HTML element</h3>
                                    <p>The main parts of our element are:</p>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>
                                            <strong>The opening tag:</strong>
                                            This consists of the name of the
                                            element (in this case, p), wrapped
                                            in opening and closing
                                            <strong>angle brackets</strong>.
                                            This states where the element begins
                                            or starts to take effect — in this
                                            case where the start of the
                                            paragraph is.
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <strong>The closing tag:</strong>
                                            This is the same as the opening tag,
                                            except that it includes a forward
                                            slash before the element name. This
                                            states where the element ends — in
                                            this case where the end of the
                                            paragraph is. Failing to include a
                                            closing tag is a common beginner
                                            error and can lead to strange
                                            results.
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <strong>The content:</strong> This
                                            is the content of the element, which
                                            in this case is just text.
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <strong>The element:</strong> The
                                            opening tag plus the closing tag
                                            plus the content equals the element.
                                        </li>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </section>

                        <section class="main-section" id="What’s_in_the_head?">
                            <header>
                                <h2>What’s in the head?</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p>
                                The head of an HTML document is the part that is
                                not displayed in the web browser when the page
                                is loaded. It contains information such as the
                                page
                                <code class="inline-code">&lt;title&gt;</code>,
                                links to CSS (if you choose to style your HTML
                                content with CSS), links to custom favicons, and
                                other metadata (data about the HTML, such as the
                                author, and important keywords that describe the
                                document.) In this article we'll cover all of
                                the above and more, in order to give you a good
                                basis for working with markup.
                            </p>
                            <article>
                                <div id="What_is_the_HTML_head?">
                                    <h3>What is the HTML head?</h3>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&lt;html&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;head&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;meta charset="utf-8"/&gt;</code>          
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;title&gt;My test page&lt;/title&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/head&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;p&gt;This is my page&lt;/p&gt;</code>     
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/body&gt;</code>                          
                                    <code>&lt;/html&gt;</code>
                                </pre>
                                    <p>
                                        The HTML head is the contents of the
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;head&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element — unlike the contents of the
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;body&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element (which are displayed on the page
                                        when loaded in a browser), the head's
                                        content is not displayed on the page.
                                        Instead, the head's job is to contain
                                        metadata about the document. In the
                                        above example, the head is quite small:
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Adding_a_title">
                                    <h3>Adding a title</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        We've already seen the
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;title&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element in action — this can be used to
                                        add a title to the document. This
                                        however can get confused with the
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h1&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element, which is used to add a top
                                        level heading to your body content —
                                        this is also sometimes referred to as
                                        the page title. But they are different
                                        things!
                                    </p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            The
                                            <code class="inline-code"
                                                >&lt;h1&gt;</code
                                            >
                                            element appears on the page when
                                            loaded in the browser — generally
                                            this should be used once per page,
                                            to mark up the title of your page
                                            content (the story title, or news
                                            headline, or whatever is appropriate
                                            to your usage.)
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            The
                                            <code class="inline-code"
                                                >&lt;title&gt;</code
                                            >
                                            element is metadata that represents
                                            the title of the overall HTML
                                            document (not the document's
                                            content.)
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </section>

                        <section
                            class="main-section"
                            id="HTML_text_fundamentals"
                        >
                            <header>
                                <h2>HTML text fundamentals</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p>
                                One of HTML's main jobs is to give text
                                structure and meaning (also known as semantics)
                                so that a browser can display it correctly. This
                                article explains the way HTML can be used to
                                structure a page of text by adding headings and
                                paragraphs, emphasizing words, creating lists,
                                and more.
                            </p>
                            <article>
                                <div id="Headings_and_Paragraphs">
                                    <h3>Headings and Paragraphs</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Most structured text consists of
                                        headings and paragraphs, whether you are
                                        reading a story, a newspaper, a college
                                        textbook, a magazine, etc. Structured
                                        content makes the reading experience
                                        easier and more enjoyable.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        In HTML, each paragraph has to be
                                        wrapped in a
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;p&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element, like so:
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>&lt;p&gt;I am a paragraph, oh yes I am.&lt;/p&gt;</code>
                                </pre>
                                    <p>
                                        Each heading has to be wrapped in a
                                        heading element:
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>&lt;h1&gt;I am the title of the story.&lt;/h1&gt;</code>
                                </pre>
                                    <p>
                                        There are six heading elements —
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h1&gt;</code
                                        >,
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h2&gt;</code
                                        >,
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h3&gt;</code
                                        >,
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h4&gt;</code
                                        >,
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h5&gt;</code
                                        >, and
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h6&gt;</code
                                        >. Each element represents a different
                                        level of content in the document;
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h1&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        represents the main heading,
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h2&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        represents subheadings,
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;h3&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        represents sub-subheadings, and so on.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Lists">
                                    <h3>Lists</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Now let's turn our attention to lists.
                                        Lists are everywhere in life — from your
                                        shopping list to the list of directions
                                        you subconsciously follow to get to your
                                        house every day, to the lists of
                                        instructions you are following in these
                                        tutorials! Lists are everywhere on the
                                        Web too, and we've got three different
                                        types to worry about.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Unordered lists are used to mark up
                                        lists of items for which the order of
                                        the items doesn't matter.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Ordered lists are lists in which the
                                        order of the items does matter.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        It is perfectly ok to nest one list
                                        inside another one. You might want to
                                        have some sub-bullets sitting below a
                                        top level bullet.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </section>

                        <section class="main-section" id="Creating_hyperlinks">
                            <header>
                                <h2>Creating hyperlinks</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p>
                                Hyperlinks are really important — they are what
                                makes the Web a web. This article shows the
                                syntax required to make a link, and discusses
                                link best practices.
                            </p>
                            <article>
                                <div id="What_is_a_hyperlink?">
                                    <h3>What is a hyperlink</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Hyperlinks are one of the most exciting
                                        innovations the Web has to offer. Well,
                                        they've been a feature of the Web since
                                        the very beginning, but they are what
                                        makes the Web a Web — they allow us to
                                        link our documents to any other document
                                        (or other resource) we want to, we can
                                        also link to specific parts of
                                        documents, and we can make apps
                                        available at a simple web address
                                        (contrast this to native apps, which
                                        have to be installed and all that
                                        business.) Just about any web content
                                        can be converted to a link, so that when
                                        clicked (or otherwise activated) it will
                                        make the web browser go to another web
                                        address (URL).
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Anatomy_of_a_link">
                                    <h3>Anatomy of a link</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        A basic link is created by wrapping the
                                        text (or other content, see
                                        <a
                                            href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#Block_level_links"
                                            target="_blank"
                                            >Block level links</a
                                        >) you want to turn into a link inside
                                        an
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;a&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element, and giving it an
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;href&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        attribute (also known as a
                                        <strong>Hypertext Reference</strong> ,
                                        or <strong>target</strong>) that will
                                        contain the web address you want the
                                        link to point to.
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>&lt;p&gt;I'm creating a link to</code>
                                    <code>&lt;a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/"&gt;the Mozilla homepage&lt;/a&gt;.</code>
                                    <code>&lt;/p&gt;</code>
                                </pre>
                                    <p>This gives us the following result:</p>
                                    <p>
                                        I'm creating a link to
                                        <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/"
                                            >the Mozilla homepage</a
                                        >.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </section>

                        <section
                            class="main-section"
                            id="Advanced_text_formatting"
                        >
                            <header>
                                <h2>Advanced text formatting</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p>
                                There are many other elements in a HTML for
                                formatting text, which we didn't get to in the
                                <a
                                    class="nav-link-doc"
                                    href="#HTML_text_fundamentals"
                                    >HTML text fundamentals</a
                                >
                                article. The elements described in this article
                                are less known, but still useful to know about
                                (and this is still not a complete list by any
                                means). Here you'll learn about marking up
                                quotations, description lists, computer code and
                                other related text, subscript and superscript,
                                contact information, and more.
                            </p>
                            <article>
                                <div id="Description_lists">
                                    <h3>Description lists</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        In HTML text fundamentals, we walked
                                        through how to mark up basic lists in
                                        HTML, but we didn't mention the third
                                        type of list you'll occasionally come
                                        across —
                                        <strong>description lists</strong>. The
                                        purpose of these lists is to mark up a
                                        set of items and their associated
                                        descriptions, such as terms and
                                        definitions, or questions and answers.
                                        Let's look at an example of a set of
                                        terms and definitions:
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>soliloquy</code>
                                    <code>In drama, where a character speaks to themselves, representing their inner thoughts or feelings and in the process relaying them to the audience (but not to other characters.)</code>
                                    <code>monologue</code>
                                    <code>In drama, where a character speaks their thoughts out loud to share them with the audience and any other characters present.</code>
                                    <code>aside</code>
                                    <code>In drama, where a character shares a comment only with the audience for humorous or dramatic effect. This is usually a feeling, thought or piece of additional background information</code>
                                </pre>
                                    <p>
                                        Description lists use a different
                                        wrapper than the other list types —
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;dl&gt;</code
                                        >; in addition each term is wrapped in a
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;dt&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        (description term) element, and each
                                        description is wrapped in a
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;dd&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        (description definition) element. Let's
                                        finish marking up our example:
                                    </p>
                                    <pre>
                                    <code>&lt;dl&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;dt&gt;soliloquy&lt;dt&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;dd&gt;In drama, where a character speaks to themselves, representing their inner thoughts or feelings and in the process relaying them to the audience (but not to other characters.)&lt;dt&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;dt&gt;monologue&lt;dt&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;dd&gt;In drama, where a character speaks their thoughts out loud to share them with the audience and any other characters present.&lt;dt&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;dt&gt;aside&lt;dt&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;dd&gt;In drama, where a character shares a comment only with the audience for humorous or dramatic effect. This is usually a feeling, thought, or piece of additional background information.&lt;dt&gt;</code>
                                    <code>&lt;/dl&gt;</code>
                                </pre>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Quotations">
                                    <h3>Quotations</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        HTML also has features available for
                                        marking up quotations; which element you
                                        use depends on whether you are marking
                                        up a block or inline quotation.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        If a section of block level content (be
                                        it a paragraph, multiple paragraphs, a
                                        list, etc.) is quoted from somewhere
                                        else, you should wrap it inside a
                                        <code class="inline-code"
                                            >&lt;blockquote&gt;</code
                                        >
                                        element to signify this, and include a
                                        URL pointing to the source of the quote
                                        inside a cite attribute.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </section>

                        <section class="main-section" id="Reference">
                            <header>
                                <h2>Reference</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p>
                                All the documentation in this page is taken from
                                <a
                                    href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML"
                                    target="_blanck"
                                    >MDN</a
                                >
                            </p>
                        </section>
                    </main>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <p>
                        <small
                            >&copy; 2019 Fictional Institute all rights
                            reserved</small
                        >
                    </p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
/* Color schemes */
:root {
    --background: #eee;
    --section-bg: #fff;
    --section-alt-bg: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    --nav-bg: rgb(50, 55, 63);
    --nav-bg-light: rgb(72, 75, 87);
    --header-bg: rgb(107, 117, 126);
    --focus-bg: rgb(228, 237, 255);
    --focus: rgb(36, 118, 226);
    --text-light-strong: #fff;
    --text-light-normal: rgb(185, 191, 196);
    --text-light-weak: rgb(129, 138, 146);
    --text-dark-strong: #222;
    --text-dark-normal: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    --text-dark-weak: rgb(177, 185, 202);
}

/* Basic Reset */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Basic setup */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.75em;

    color: var(--text-dark-normal);
    background-color: var(--background);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1em;

    width: 2.8em;

    color: var(--text-light-strong);
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 100;

    color: var(--text-dark-strong);
}

h3 {
    font-weight: 100;

    color: var(--text-dark-strong);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited,
a:link {
    color: var(--text-light-normal);
}

/* Utility classes */
.main-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: 8rem calc(100% - 8rem);
    grid-template-rows: 8rem calc(100% - 8rem);

    height: 100vh;
}

.padding-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: calc(100% - 5rem) 5rem;
    grid-template-rows: calc(100% - 5rem) 5rem;

    padding: 0 12rem 1rem 12rem;
}

.sub-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: 100%;
    -ms-grid-columns: 22rem 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 22rem 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;

    height: auto;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Code */
pre {
    overflow-x: auto;

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;

    counter-reset: linenumber;
    white-space: nowrap;

    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--text-light-normal);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: var(--section-alt-bg);
}

pre code::before {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;

    content: counter(linenumber) " ";
    counter-increment: linenumber;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    text-align: right;

    color: var(--text-dark-normal);
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-right-color: var(--text-dark-weak);
}

code {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: 500;

    display: block;

    color: var(--text-dark-strong);
}

.inline-code {
    display: inline;

    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;

    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--text-dark-weak);
    background-color: var(--focus-bg);
}

/* Header */
#top-header {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-grid-columns: 22rem 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 22rem 1fr;

    height: 100%;
    padding: 1.5rem 12rem;

    color: var(--text-light-normal);
    background-color: var(--header-bg);
}

.heading-start,
.heading-end {
    font-size: 0.3em;
    line-height: 0.7em;

    display: block;
}

.heading-start {
    transform: translateX(0.2em);
}
.heading-end {
    transform: translateX(-0.2em);
    text-align: right;
}

#top-header .heading-text {
    padding: 0 7rem 0 5rem;
}

/* Navbar */
aside {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    height: 100%;
    padding: 3rem 0;

    background-color: var(--nav-bg);
}

#navbar header {
    font-size: 1.1rem;

    padding: 0rem 3rem;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: var(--text-light-strong);
}

#navbar .nav-heading {
    color: var(--text-light-strong);
}

#navbar .nav-link-sub {
    color: var(--text-light-weak);
}

#navbar a {
    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0rem 3rem;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    color: var(--text-light-strong);
    background-color: var(--focus);
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar > ul > li {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

/* Main Document */
#main-doc {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    height: 100%;
    padding: 0rem 7rem 3rem 5rem;

    background-color: var(--section-bg);
}

#main-doc h2 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;

    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding-top: 3rem;
}

#main-doc > .main-section:first-of-type h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 4rem;
}

#main-doc h3 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;

    padding-top: 3rem;
}

#main-doc p,
#main-doc li:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

#main-doc li {
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
}

#main-doc ol,
#main-doc ul {
    padding-left: 2.5rem;

    list-style-position: outside;
}

#main-doc a {
    text-decoration: underline;

    color: var(--focus);
}

#main-doc .nav-link-doc {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;

    text-align: center;

    background-color: var(--section-bg);
}

/* Media queries desktop first */

/* Desktop 1600px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
    .padding-container {
        padding: 0 8rem 1rem 8rem;
    }
    #top-header {
        padding: 1.5rem 8rem;
    }
}

/* Desktop 1200px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .padding-container {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #top-header {
        padding: 1.5rem 0;
    }
    #top-header .main-heading {
        padding-left: 3rem;
    }
    #top-header .heading-text {
        padding: 0 4rem 0 4rem;
    }
    #main-doc {
        padding: 0rem 4rem 3rem 4rem;
    }
}

/* Tablet 835px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 835px) {
    #top-header {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;

        padding: 1.5rem 0;
    }
    #top-header .heading-text {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        line-height: 1.5em;

        padding: 0 4rem 0 4rem;
    }
    .main-container {
        grid-template-rows: 6rem calc(100% - 6rem);
    }
    .padding-container {
        grid-template-rows: calc(100% - 4rem) 4rem;
    }
    .sub-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 20% 80%;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    #navbar {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }
    #navbar header {
        font-size: 1rem;

        padding-bottom: 1rem;

        border-color: var(--nav-bg-light);
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
    #navbar > ul > li {
        margin-top: 0rem;
    }
    #navbar > ul > li > ul > li {
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }
    #navbar a {
        border-color: var(--nav-bg-light);
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
    #main-doc {
        padding: 0rem 3rem 3rem 3rem;
    }
    #main-doc h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        margin-top: 1rem;
        padding-top: 2rem;
    }
    #main-doc > .main-section:first-of-type h2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 3rem;
    }
    #main-doc h3 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;

        padding-top: 2rem;
    }
    aside {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
}

/* Phone 568px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    #top-header {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 100%;

        padding: 1rem 0;
    }
    #top-header .heading-text {
        display: none;
    }
    #top-header .main-heading {
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        display: inline;
    }
    #top-header .heading-start,
    #top-header .heading-end {
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 1em;

        display: inline;
    }
    .heading-start {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .heading-end {
        transform: translateX(0);
        text-align: left;
    }
    .main-container {
        grid-template-rows: 3.5rem calc(100% - 3.5rem);
    }
    .padding-container {
        grid-template-rows: calc(100% - 3rem) 3rem;
    }
    .sub-container {
        grid-template-rows: 20% 80%;
    }
    #navbar {
        padding: 1rem 0;
    }

    #navbar header {
        padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;
    }
    #navbar a {
        padding: 0rem 1rem;
    }
    #main-doc {
        padding: 0rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
    }
    #main-doc h2 {
        font-size: 1.4rem;

        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-top: 1.5rem;
    }
    #main-doc > .main-section:first-of-type h2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 2rem;
    }
    #main-doc h3 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;

        padding-top: 1.5rem;
    }
    aside {
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }
    footer {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        line-height: 1rem;

        margin-top: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides small points like the use of `&nbsp;` to indent, `<code>` unsemantically, everything looks well organized with a lot of effort in styling.

And that leads me to the main point:

**It would be better to separate text content and styling.**

And that would mean an XML format with a custom XML-to-HTML XSL transformation.
There are some XML formats like SimpleDocBook that can cover much. You might even combine things by custom XML to docbook XML to HTML. Or PDF.

So my advice: make the text content, and its editing the main concern,
and then add conversion to HTML.

XML may be validated by an XSD or DTD for instance. There might be a usable XML editor that can do autocompletion and such.

I love documentation, but you are risking "editing by copying HTML snippets." That is not good for reuse, starting clean.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will look into XML for future projects.